# A ListView column with an image in its data template is not visible

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following three data templates:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:DirOrFileItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="../Images/Folder.png"  Stretch="Uniform" Height="20"></Image>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding RelativePath}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SelectColTemplate">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="IconTemplate">
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageData}" Stretch="Uniform" Height="20" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I set the `ImageData` property on the row viewmodel as follows:

```
item.ImageData = ImageHelper.LoadImage(AppConstants.FileRsourcePath);
```

where `LoadImage` is:

```
public static BitmapImage LoadImage(string filename)
{
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + filename));
}
```

I know it loads the image correctly because when I examine the `ImageData` property after setting it, it has properties that are correct for the image that was loaded.

The `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is for a `TreeView`, and the image `folder.png` appears as and where expected. Then I have the following `ListView` columns:

```
<GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource SelectColTemplate}" Width="30" />
<GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource IconTemplate}" Width="30" />
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="360" />
```

I am displaying a list of files and folders, and would like an image to highlight which is which.

The `CheckBox` appears where it should, in the first column, and the third column in the markup appears as the second column on screen, as if the column with the image template, `IconTemplate`, does not exist.

Both images are where they should be, in the same `Images` folder, so why is my "image column" not appearing as the second column as I expect?

**BONUS QUESTION:** If, as @Clemens suggests below in his comment, I set the Build Action of the images to `Resource` and and load them by Resource File Pack URIs, how would I do so in XAML?

Comment: `../Images/Folder.png` looks odd. Instead of loading images from relative file paths, consider adding the image files to your Visual Studio project (in a project folder `Images`), set their Build Action to Resource, and load them by Resource File Pack URIs, which you could write like `Images/Folder.png` in XAML.

Comment: Perhaps utilize a converter to bind to image source?

Comment: @Clemens, I like your idea much more than referencing raw files, thanks, but that still doesn't answer why one `Image` element works and the other one doesn't, with the same image path.

Comment: Just an assumption with out testing but the Hierarchical will be looking at the DataContext of the source, while DataTemplate is only looking at the DataContext of the instance. I'd bet if you tweaked the DataContext.path of the second image it would work but @Clemens approach is the better route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set Build Action in your image properties to Resource and set full path to your image. It will appear.
http://prntscr.com/jjw4z3

Comment: I know how to set a build action to `Resource`, but normally in C# you have to use the full assembly name and path, and wondered if there was a difference for XAML. Like a reference to a resource pack or something. So it's just `<Image Source="Images/Folder.png"...` and it will find it in the resources?

Comment: No, there is nothing special you need to do for xaml. <Image Source="Images/Folder.png"> will just find the image in the Images folder.

Answer (score 1):

As long you don't need to destroy it....you don't have to load the image, just give the URI in the binding  ==> ImageData = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + filename)); and the Image control will load it

btw, your viewmodel must not have GUI related element like bitmap image
bye.

Comment: Thanks for the viewmodel tip, but unfortunately time constraints have made this project a bit of a code-behind/MVVM hybrid.